# How to Split a string via regular expressions and keep the pattern in output?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, preg-split

I have some code here:

```
$testString = "text23hello54stack90overflow34test";
$testArray = preg_split("/[0-9]{2}/Uim", $testString);
echo "<pre>".print_r($testArray)."</pre>";
```

After execution of these commands i have an array containing:

```
{text, hello, stack, overflow, test}
```

And I want to modify it so i get:

```
{text, 23hello, 54stack, 90overflow, 34test}
```

How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$testString = "text23hello54stack90overflow34test";
$testArray = preg_split("/(?=[0-9]{2})/Uim", $testString);
echo print_r($testArray);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => text
    [1] => 23hello
    [2] => 54stack
    [3] => 90overflow
    [4] => 34test
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_replace()`:

```
$testString = "text23hello54stack90overflow34test";
$testArray = preg_replace("/([0-9]{2})/Uim", ', $1', $testString);

echo $testArray;
// text, 23hello, 54stack, 90overflow, 34test
```